# Have an SVG act as a block element

Tags: html, css, svg, display

I have been trying to figure out how to get my SVG element to act as display: block. I have an image I want directly below the SVG, but it keeps overlapping the SVG. I have tried changing the properties to "display: block" as well as creating a div container around the SVG element itself, but nothing seems to work. I am sure there is an easy way, I just can't figure it out.

```css
#svg{
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: auto;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        display: block;
    }
    #svgContainer{
        display: block;
        width: 90%;
        margin: auto;
    }
    #seasonImage{
        background-image: url('images/summer.png');
        width: 120%;
        margin-left: -30px;
        height: auto;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size: contain;
        height:200px;
        display: block;
        position: relative;
    }
```

```html
<div id="svgContainer">
 <svg id="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" width="90%">
  <text x="80" y="106" id="currentTemp" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" style="fill: #C9AC68">{{currentTemp}}&#176;</text>
  <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="35" stroke="#C9AC68" />
  <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="55" stroke="#B25538" />
  <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="#507282" />
  <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" stroke="#7E8959" />
     
        <circle id="line1" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="35" stroke="#C9AC68" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="126" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
  <circle id="line2" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="55" stroke="#B25538" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="188" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
  <circle id="line3" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="#507282" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="251" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
  <circle id="line4" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" stroke="#7E8959" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="314" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
 </svg>
</div>

<div id="seasonImage"></div>
```

THANKS!

Comment: Remove the `position: absolute;` for the svg element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSS sets `position: absolute` to the `svg` element. Unlike statically positioned elements, absolutely positioned elements do not take the space they need to fit in their containers. The Browser places them at the coordinates you specify with `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom`, whether that's underneath or on top of any other element.

From your `#seasonImage` element's point of view, nothing is occupating the space above itself. Therefore, the browser places it at the top of its container, overlapping the absolutely positioned SVG.

If we comment out or remove `position: absolute;` (and its related properties), the browser will place the image directly below the SVG.

```css
#svg {
  /*position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;*/
  margin: auto;
  /*z-index: -1;*/
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
}

#svgContainer {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

#seasonImage {
  background-image: url('https://cataas.com/cat?26');
  width: 120%;
  margin-left: -30px;
  height: auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  height: 200px;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="svgContainer">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="-10 -10 220 220" width="90%">
            <text x="80" y="106" id="currentTemp" font-size="18" font-weight="bold" style="fill: #C9AC68">{{currentTemp}}&#176;</text>
            <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="35" stroke="#C9AC68" />
            <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="55" stroke="#B25538" />
            <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="#507282" />
            <circle class="background" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" stroke="#7E8959" />

            <circle id="line1" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="35" stroke="#C9AC68" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="126" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
            <circle id="line2" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="55" stroke="#B25538" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="188" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
            <circle id="line3" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="75" stroke="#507282" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="251" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
            <circle id="line4" class="overlayLine" cx="100" cy="100" r="95" stroke="#7E8959" stroke-dasharray="0, 3000" stroke-dashoffset="314" transform="rotate(-90,100,100)" />
        </svg>
</div>

<div id="seasonImage"></div>
```